# JTable to a Parent JPanel with GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

So for a school project I have to add a JTable to a JPanel in a separate class without modifying the latter. This is the class where the JPanel is located.

```
public class ThisSwingView extends SwingView implements ThisTCRMView {

public ThisSwingView() {
    super();
    setTitle("This");

    JScrollPane centerScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    centerScrollPane.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    centerScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    centerScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    setCenterPanel(centerScrollPane);


    JPanel centerGrid = new JPanel();
    centerScrollPane.setViewportView(centerGrid);
    GridBagLayout gbl_centerGrid = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_centerGrid.columnWidths = new int[]{100, 475, 0};
    gbl_centerGrid.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_centerGrid.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_centerGrid.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    centerGrid.setLayout(gbl_centerGrid);}}
```

This is the class I can modify:

```
public class NewThisSwingView extends ThisSwingView implements ThisTCRMSales{

public NewThisSwingView(){
    super();
    JPanel centerGrid = new JPanel();
    JTable table;
    Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
            { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };
    Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
    table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_Table = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_contactsTable.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_contactsTable.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_contactsTable.gridx = 1;
    gbc_contactsTable.gridy = 12;
    centerGrid.add(table, gbc_Table);
}}
```

However, when I do this, my table will not print on the screen. I have already modified the main class to run the class I am modifying but it won't work. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `centerGrid` is never added to `NewThisSwingView` ... but I can't see anywhere that you're using `NewThisSwingView`, so, it's never getting added to anything either.  This raises a bunch of new questions - like why you're not wrapping the `JTable` in it's own `JScrollPane`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below add table in JScrollPane

```
public class NewThisSwingView extends ThisSwingView implements ThisTCRMSales{

    public NewThisSwingView(){
        super();
        JPanel centerGrid = new JPanel();
        JTable table;
        Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
                { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };
        Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
        table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_Table = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_contactsTable.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_contactsTable.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_contactsTable.gridx = 1;
        gbc_contactsTable.gridy = 12;

        // wrap table inside JScrollPane
        centerGrid.add(new JScrollPane(table), gbc_Table);
    }
}
```